# Declare member variables that do not have a default constructor nor a copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Assume I have class `Member` that does not have neither a default constructor nor a copy constructor, and it gets created by a third party API as with a function.

I have the declarations

```
Member CreateMember(string str);

class MyClass {
    Member my_member;
public:
    MyClass(){
       my_member = CreateMember("I am a parameter");
    }
}
```

Since the class `Member` has no default constructor, the above declaration doesn't work, as there is no way to initialize the member.

I also cannot declare it as a pointer, since the lack of copy constructor means I can't call `new Member(my_member)`.

I am at a loss here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Member CreateMember(string str);

class MyClass {
    Member my_member;
public:
    MyClass()
    : my_member(CreateMember("I am a parameter"))
    {
    }
};
```